# Formating issues with some chars but fine with others

Tags: c

Having a couple issues with this calculator I'm trying to write. Not 100% sure if this is formating or something else. The first issue is that it will not print the results after use of + and -, C (for clear) and T which is setting the accumulator to the following number. It works fine on * and /. 
Another issue is with the printing of arrays which I'm saving all the input to. 
It works fine for some of the input, but the formating is all weird. Some chars wont show and some of the floats are wrong, others are right. I'm hoping someone can clear it up for me.

I've tried making small adjustments, but this is as close to goal as I have gotten.

```
int main(){
    float tall[STRLEN], input,
    akkumulator = 0.0;   
    char tegn[STRLEN], operator;
    int i = 0; 

    printf("Kalkulator\n");
    printf("= %f", akkumulator);
    do{ 

        i += 1; 
        printf("\n: ");
        scanf("%c", &operator); char check = toupper(operator); 
        scanf("%f", &input);

            switch (check){
                case '*':
                    akkumulator *= input;
                    tegn[i] = '*';
                    tall[i] = input;
                    printf("\n= %f", akkumulator);
                    break;
                case '+':
                    akkumulator += input;
                    tegn[i] = '+';
                    tall[i] = input;
                    printf("\n= %f", akkumulator);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    akkumulator -= input;
                    tegn[i] = '-';
                    tall[i] = input;
                    printf("\n= %f", akkumulator);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    akkumulator /= input;
                    tegn[i] = '/';
                    tall[i] = input;
                    printf("\n= %f", akkumulator);
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    akkumulator = 0.0;
                    tegn[i] = 'C';
                    tall[i] = input;
                    printf("\n= %f", akkumulator);
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    akkumulator = input;
                    tegn[i] = 'T';
                    tall[i] = input;
                    printf("\n= %f", akkumulator);
                    break;
                default:
                    break; 
            }

        if(tegn[i] == '/' && tall == 0)
            printf("\n You can not do that");  
        else if(operator == 'S')
            for(int y = 0; y<i; y++){
                printf("\n%2c %5f", tegn[y], tall[y]);
            }

    }while(operator != 'S');


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "weird" in terms of specific output you get.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: `i` is 1 before the very first `scanf` so `tegn[0]` and `tall[0]` will never get set to anything. The loop that prints `tegn[y]` and `tall[y]` will print junk when `y` is 0.

Comment: @user3121023 thanks, man!! I did it too %f, but didn't know it was like that for chars aswell. It solved the issue with +, - not printing an answer.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are right, Ian! Thanks, a lot. I changed the for loop to int i = 1 and that solved it.

Comment: Im still having the issue of lower case S and C not working, while T works perfectly. I can't see how I am using the toupper function wrong. Any tips?

Comment: I don't see a problem with C, but for S you compare `operator` instead of `check`. However, learn to debug, the most simple way is to put some `printf()` here and there to watch your variables and flow of control.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, in this kind of situation, `for` loop would be much more helpful than `do while()` loop. And for the division by zero, you already have `case '/':`, so it would be better if you put your `printf("\n You can not do that");` in `switch`.

1. You have two `scanf()`s at the beginning of your loop, and that means you need to put your input like

```
C
13.45
```

to continue the loop. Moreover, even if you put two inputs like

```
C
45.23
```

, the next scanf for operator gets `\n` due to your input buffer. Adding a `getchar()` after `scanf("%f", &input);` will fix that problem.
Finally, your `do while()` loop's termination condition is `operator != 'S'`, yet `operator` remains `'s'` because what changes to uppercase letter is `check`, not `operator`. This would be the reason why your calculator won't end even if you type s.

2. You are saving your operator and input value in your arrays starting on i = 1, while printing your array starting from zero. Changing

```c
for(int y = 0; y<i; y++){
    printf("\n%2c %5f", tegn[y], tall[y]);
}
```

into

```c
for(int y = 1; y <= i; y++){
    printf("\n%2c %5f", tegn[y], tall[y]);
}
```

will fix your problem